# Calculate the average of an double array rows

Tags: c#, arrays, integer, double, average

I'm trying to figure out how to calculate the average value of each row in my array, but I've only found answers on how to do it with int arrays. I'm super beginner in programming, but I think I got some of it right in my code, there's just one thing I don't understand how to fix.
I get some average values when I print this, but they're way off.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double[,] dTaulu = new double[5, 4]; //<--- this is my issue I think, why are those numbers Int32?
        double i;
        double j;

        for (i = 0; i < 1; i++)
        {
            for(j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            {
                Console.Write("Anna maanantain {0} sademäärä: ", j + 1);
                dTaulu[(int)i,(int)j] = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());      
            }
        }
        for ( i = 1; i < 2; i++)
        {
            for( j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            {
                Console.Write("Anna tiistain {0} sademäärä: ", j + 1);
                dTaulu[(int)i, (int)j] = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            }
        }
        for ( i = 2; i < 3; i++)
        {
            for ( j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            {
                Console.Write("Anna keskiviikon {0} sademäärä: ", j + 1);
                dTaulu[(int)i,(int)j] = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            }
        }
        for ( i = 3; i < 4; i++)
        {
            for ( j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            {
                Console.Write("Anna torstain {0} sademäärä: ", j + 1);
                dTaulu[(int)i,(int) j] = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            }
        }
        for (i = 4; i < 5; i++)
        {
            for(j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            {
                Console.Write("Anna perjantain {0} sademäärä: ", j + 1);
                dTaulu[(int)i, (int)j] = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            }
        }
        double average1 = dTaulu[0,0] + dTaulu[0,1] + dTaulu[0,2] + dTaulu[0,3] / 4;
        double average2 = dTaulu[1,0] + dTaulu[1,1] + dTaulu[1,2] + dTaulu[1,3] / 4;
        double average3 = dTaulu[2,0] + dTaulu[2,1] + dTaulu[2,2] + dTaulu[2,3] / 4;
        double average4 = dTaulu[3,0] + dTaulu[3,1] + dTaulu[3,2] + dTaulu[3,3] / 4;
        double average5 = dTaulu[4,0] + dTaulu[4,1] + dTaulu[4,2] + dTaulu[4,3] / 4;  //I couldn't figure out how to use dTaulu.Average

        
        Console.WriteLine("Maanantai: {0} mm\nTiistai: {1} mm\nKeskiviikko: {2} mm\nTorstai: {3} mm\nPerjantai: {4} mm",average1,average2,average3,average4,average5);
        Console.ReadKey();                    
    }
```

Comment: If you make `i` and `j` an `int` rather than `double` you won't have to cast them all over the place.

Answer (score 2):

The problem doesn't have to do with integers. All of your variables are properly `double` and the expressions they are involved in will automatically promote integer literals to double as well. The problem is here:

```
double average1 = dTaulu[0,0] + dTaulu[0,1] + dTaulu[0,2] + dTaulu[0,3] / 4;
```

Remember the order of operator precedence here. `/` binds tighter than `+` so this is wrong. You must write:

```
double average1 = (dTaulu[0,0] + dTaulu[0,1] + dTaulu[0,2] + dTaulu[0,3]) / 4;
```

Comment: Oh my god, I can't believe I completely blanked on that. Thanks man, I guess this is what happens when you're still writing code at 4am :D

Answer (score 0):

I recommend learning to use loops. They will make your work easier, your code more readable, and the code will then work with any size of array. If you write the code like below, then if you want to change the dimensions of the array to say [10,10] then all you have to do is change the first line instead of rewriting the whole thing.

```
double[,] dTaulu = new double[5, 4];

for (int row = 0; row < dTaulu.GetLength(0); row++)
{
    for (int col = 0; col < dTaulu.GetLength(1); col++)
    {
        Console.Write($"Anna maanantain {col + 1} sademäärä: ");
        dTaulu[row, col] = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    }
}

double[] averages = new double[dTaulu.GetLength(0)];
for (int row = 0; row < dTaulu.GetLength(0); row++)
{
    double sum = 0;
    for (int col = 0; col < dTaulu.GetLength(1); col++)
    {
        sum += dTaulu[row, col];
    }
    averages[row] = sum / dTaulu.GetLength(1);
}
```

Comment: I did something like this originally, and it works, but in the program I'm asking inputs for different weekdays (Maanantai, Tiistai, Keskiviikko etc) so that was the shortest I could get it with my knowledge. With your code I would be asking inputs for monday 5 times in a row, which is not what I want.
I will definitely learn to use loops more in the future tho, so thanks for the tip :P

Comment: @SamuliKuusisto In that case you need to create an array with the weekday strings and add the weekday to the interpolated string. Something like `Console.Write($"Anna {weekDayNames[row]} {col + 1} sademäärä: ");` ... If you can't figure out how to do it, write a comment and I will add it to the answer when I have the time